# How to run a code only when user changes page in React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Let there are 4 pages (page1, page2, page3, page4) in React application.

I want to run a code only when user move from page3 to any other page i.e. just before changing page.

Comment: need some more details here, but you might want to look at component mounting: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount (Class) or https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html (Functional). You may also find use out of https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a wrapper component that calls the desired code in a callback when the component unmounts.

Example wrapper component:

```
const UnmountCallback = ({ children, onUnmount }) => {
  useEffect(() => onUnmount, []);
  return children;
};
```

### react-router-dom v6

Render the routes and for the component that you want to call when it is navigated away from wrap with the `UnmountCallback` wrapper component.

```
const unMountCallback = () => console.log("Left page 3!!");

...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/page1" element={<Component1 />} />
  <Route path="/page2" element={<Component2 />} />
  <Route
    path="/page3"
    element={
      <UnmountCallback onUnmount={unMountCallback}>
        <Component3 />
      </UnmountCallback>
    }
  />
  <Route path="/page4" element={<Component4 />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-run-a-code-only-when-user-changes-page-in-react-js]

### react-router-dom v4/5

If you are still on v5 of `react-router-dom` the process is similar and you switch over to the `render` prop and render an anonymous component.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/page1" component={Component1} />
  <Route path="/page2" component={Component2} />
  <Route
    path="/page3"
    render={(props) => (
      <UnmountCallback onUnmount={unMountCallback}>
        <Component3 {...props} />
      </UnmountCallback>
    )}
  />
  <Route path="/page4" component={Component3} />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit how-to-run-a-code-only-when-user-changes-page-in-react-js (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that pass a `state` from page 3 to page 4 and add that as a dependency in the mounting of page 4 component and then, use an observer (like `useEffect`) to only run a chunk of code when this `state` is received by page 4 component.

Pseudo code :

Parent component for route definitions

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/page1'} component = {Page1}/>
        <Route path={'/page2'} component = {Page2}/>
        <Route path={'/page3'} component = {Page3}/>
        <Route path={'/page4'} component = {Page4}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Page3 component, linking to page 4 and passing it's own pathname (i.e. routename) as a prop

```
const Page3 = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={{pathname: '/page4', state: { prevPath: location.pathname }}}>Example Link</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Page4 component which receives the location of the page we are just coming from.

If received location is that of Page3, we run some code

```
const Page4 = ({location}) => {
  const path = location.state.prevPath
  const isComingFromPageThree = path === "/page3"

  if (isComingFromPageThree) {
    console.log('run this code')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      page 4
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is another way to render a component based on some props that it receives which can be used by it to conditionally run some code. [Reference](https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)